# Formatting timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-char

I have the below date in a table.

Table APEX

```
id     search_date
 1     04-OCT-18 08.36.12.000000 PM
```

I would like it to display as the below format. Is this possible?

```
id     search_date
 1     10/4/2018 8:36.12
```

Comment: Wernfried has the best option I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I order to suppress leading zeros you can use the [FM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) switch:

```
to_char(search_date,'mm/FMdd/yyyy hh:mi.ss')
```

In case you like to suppress leading zeros also from month, it would be

```
to_char(search_date,'FMmm/dd/yyyy hh:mi.ss')
```

Note, `FM` acts as a switch, i.e. you turn off and on leading zeros and spaces.

For example `'FMmm/FMdd/yyyy hh:mi.ss'` means: `mm` is truncated but `dd/yyyy hh:mi.ss` will not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char`, `replace` and `ltrim` string operator functions together :

```
select replace(to_char(search_date,'mm/dd/yyyy '),'/0','/')||
       ltrim(to_char(search_date,'hh:mi.ss'),'0') as search_date
  from apex;

SEARCH_DATE
-----------------
10/4/2018 8:36.12
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a9fbd4a06e7ec828fb41a1c2e0a7c57)</kbd>

Comment: What about the AM and PM?

Comment: @MrJohn already included in the Demo with PM for the insert statement.

Comment: Using [FM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) would be shorter: `to_char(search_date,'mm/FMddFM/yyyy FMhh:mi.ss')`

Comment: your has very good style @WernfriedDomscheit I think you should convert to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TO_CHAR()` and `TO_DATE()`:

It could be the partial answer, with out the `.000000 PM` in the input

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('04-OCT-18 08.36.12','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Result
FROM DUAL;
```

Result as [`10/04/2018 08:36:12`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1c0b4ce2288bda07f7633b0be0e1ef3)

---

**UPDATE**: Using `TO_CHAR()` and `TO_TIMESTAMP()`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('04-OCT-18 08.36.12.000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF PM'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Result
FROM DUAL;
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e05db0b1f07d278e57171e6fa32cb7d), will result as `10/04/2018 20:36:12`

Using this `04-OCT-18 08.36.12.000000 AM` will result as `10/04/2018 08:36:12`, [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=182c87ceb243f8febcfff41c591f142f) for the same.

Comment: How can I remove the .00000 PM?